# Using a foreign key's attribute as a field in a model

Tags: python, django, database

Let's say I have these as a code

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    total_transaction = get_price()
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon,on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def get_price(self):
        return self.item.price * self.coupon.percentage // 100
```

I want to use the coupon's percentage and item's price to put in total_transaction, but i don't seem to be able to pass in the function as it says "self" is required?
How do I work around this?

Comment: You do, but you need to pass a transaction *object*, not the transaction *class*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry but, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `total_transaction` as a property:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon,on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    @property
    def total_transaction(self):
        return self.item.price * self.coupon.percentage // 100
```

Note: Properties do not get saved to DB